# How to create full screen mode for youtube videos in pyqt5 webbrowser

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have created webbrowser to search on the Internet.

The problem is that on the youtube full screen site I can't make it work the way I want it to full screen, but when I exit full screen mode, I get two windows instead of one or if I get stuck with a window, I delete QWebEngineView.

My PyQt5 version is 5.13.2

My code is below

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
import os 
import sys 

# main window 
class MainWindow(QMainWindow): 

    # constructor 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs) 

        # creating a tab widget 
        self.tabs = QTabWidget() 

        # making document mode true 
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True) 

        # adding action when double clicked 
        self.tabs.tabBarDoubleClicked.connect(self.tab_open_doubleclick) 

        # adding action when tab is changed 
        self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.current_tab_changed) 

        # making tabs closeable 
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True) 

        # adding action when tab close is requested 
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_current_tab) 

        # making tabs as central widget 
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs) 

        # creating a status bar 
        self.status = QStatusBar() 

        # setting status bar to the main window 
        self.setStatusBar(self.status) 

        # creating a tool bar for navigation 
        navtb = QToolBar("Navigation") 

        # adding tool bar tot he main window 
        self.addToolBar(navtb) 

        # creating back action 
        back_btn = QAction("Back", self) 

        # setting status tip 
        back_btn.setStatusTip("Back to previous page") 

        # adding action to back button 
        # making current tab to go back 
        back_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().back()) 

        # adding this to the navigation tool bar 
        navtb.addAction(back_btn) 

        # similarly adding next button 
        next_btn = QAction("Forward", self) 
        next_btn.setStatusTip("Forward to next page") 
        next_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().forward()) 
        navtb.addAction(next_btn) 

        # similarly adding reload button 
        reload_btn = QAction("Reload", self) 
        reload_btn.setStatusTip("Reload page") 
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().reload()) 
        navtb.addAction(reload_btn) 

        # creating home action 
        home_btn = QAction("Home", self) 
        home_btn.setStatusTip("Go home") 

        # adding action to home button 
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home) 
        navtb.addAction(home_btn) 

        # adding a separator 
        navtb.addSeparator() 

        # creating a line edit widget for URL 
        self.urlbar = QLineEdit() 

        # adding action to line edit when return key is pressed 
        self.urlbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url) 

        # adding line edit to tool bar 
        navtb.addWidget(self.urlbar) 

        # similarly adding stop action 
        stop_btn = QAction("Stop", self) 
        stop_btn.setStatusTip("Stop loading current page") 
        stop_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().stop()) 
        navtb.addAction(stop_btn) 

        # creating first tab 
        self.add_new_tab(QUrl('http://www.google.com'), 'Homepage') 

        # showing all the components 
        self.show() 

        # setting window title 
        self.setWindowTitle("Aashra") 

    # method for adding new tab 
    def add_new_tab(self, qurl = None, label ="Blank", text = "New Tab"): 

        # if url is blank 
        if qurl is None: 
            # creating a google url 
            qurl = QUrl('http://www.google.com') 

        # creating a QWebEngineView object 
        browser = QWebEngineView() 

        # setting url to browser 
        browser.setUrl(qurl) 

        # setting tab index 
        i = self.tabs.addTab(browser, label) 
        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(i) 

        # adding action to the browser when url is changed 
        # update the url 
        browser.urlChanged.connect(lambda qurl, browser = browser: 
                                self.update_urlbar(qurl, browser)) 

        # adding action to the browser when loading is finished 
        # set the tab title 
        browser.loadFinished.connect(lambda _, i = i, browser = browser: 
                                    self.tabs.setTabText(i, browser.page().title())) 

    # when double clicked is pressed on tabs 
    def tab_open_doubleclick(self, i): 

        # checking index i.e 
        # No tab under the click 
        if i == -1: 
            # creating a new tab 
            self.add_new_tab() 

    # wen tab is changed 
    def current_tab_changed(self, i): 

        # get the curl 
        qurl = self.tabs.currentWidget().url() 

        # update the url 
        self.update_urlbar(qurl, self.tabs.currentWidget()) 

        # update the title 
        self.update_title(self.tabs.currentWidget()) 

    # when tab is closed 
    def close_current_tab(self, i): 

        # if there is only one tab 
        if self.tabs.count() < 2: 
            # do nothing 
            return

        # else remove the tab 
        self.tabs.removeTab(i) 

    # method for updating the title 
    def update_title(self, browser): 

        # if signal is not from the current tab 
        if browser != self.tabs.currentWidget(): 
            # do nothing 
            return

        # get the page title 
        title = self.tabs.currentWidget().page().title() 

    # action to go to home 
    def navigate_home(self): 

        # go to google 
        self.tabs.currentWidget().setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com")) 

    # method for navigate to url 
    def navigate_to_url(self): 

        # get the line edit text 
        # convert it to QUrl object 
        q = QUrl(self.urlbar.text()) 

        # if scheme is blank 
        if q.scheme() == "": 
            # set scheme 
            q.setScheme("http") 

        # set the url 
        self.tabs.currentWidget().setUrl(q) 

    # method to update the url 
    def update_urlbar(self, q, browser = None): 
        # If this signal is not from the current tab, ignore 
        if browser != self.tabs.currentWidget(): 
            return

        # set text to the url bar 
        self.urlbar.setText(q.toString()) 

        # set cursor position 
        self.urlbar.setCursorPosition(0)

        def _downloadRequested(item): # QWebEngineDownloadItem
            print('downloading to', item.path())
            item.accept()

        browser.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(_downloadRequested) 

# creating a PyQt5 application 
app = QApplication(sys.argv) 

# setting name to the application 
app.setApplicationName("Aashra") 

# creating MainWindow object 
window = MainWindow() 

# loop 
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to activate the FullScreenSupportEnabled flag so that you can use the fullScreenRequested signal that will notify when the browser requires the window to change state. In a method connected to fullScreenRequested you must use showFullScreen() and hide the other widgets when the request's toggleOn() is True, and showNormal() and show the hidden widgets when false.

```py
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtPrintSupport import *
import os
import sys

# main window
class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    # constructor
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # creating a tab widget
        self.tabs = QTabWidget()

        # making document mode true
        self.tabs.setDocumentMode(True)

        # adding action when double clicked
        self.tabs.tabBarDoubleClicked.connect(self.tab_open_doubleclick)

        # adding action when tab is changed
        self.tabs.currentChanged.connect(self.current_tab_changed)

        # making tabs closeable
        self.tabs.setTabsClosable(True)

        # adding action when tab close is requested
        self.tabs.tabCloseRequested.connect(self.close_current_tab)

        # making tabs as central widget
        self.setCentralWidget(self.tabs)

        # creating a status bar
        self.status = QStatusBar()

        # setting status bar to the main window
        self.setStatusBar(self.status)

        # creating a tool bar for navigation
        self.navtb = QToolBar("Navigation")

        # adding tool bar tot he main window
        self.addToolBar(self.navtb)

        # creating back action
        back_btn = QAction("Back", self)

        # setting status tip
        back_btn.setStatusTip("Back to previous page")

        # adding action to back button
        # making current tab to go back
        back_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().back())

        # adding this to the navigation tool bar
        self.navtb.addAction(back_btn)

        # similarly adding next button
        next_btn = QAction("Forward", self)
        next_btn.setStatusTip("Forward to next page")
        next_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().forward())
        self.navtb.addAction(next_btn)

        # similarly adding reload button
        reload_btn = QAction("Reload", self)
        reload_btn.setStatusTip("Reload page")
        reload_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().reload())
        self.navtb.addAction(reload_btn)

        # creating home action
        home_btn = QAction("Home", self)
        home_btn.setStatusTip("Go home")

        # adding action to home button
        home_btn.triggered.connect(self.navigate_home)
        self.navtb.addAction(home_btn)

        # adding a separator
        self.navtb.addSeparator()

        # creating a line edit widget for URL
        self.urlbar = QLineEdit()

        # adding action to line edit when return key is pressed
        self.urlbar.returnPressed.connect(self.navigate_to_url)

        # adding line edit to tool bar
        self.navtb.addWidget(self.urlbar)

        # similarly adding stop action
        stop_btn = QAction("Stop", self)
        stop_btn.setStatusTip("Stop loading current page")
        stop_btn.triggered.connect(lambda: self.tabs.currentWidget().stop())
        self.navtb.addAction(stop_btn)

        # creating first tab
        self.add_new_tab(QUrl("http://www.google.com"), "Homepage")

        # showing all the components
        self.show()

        # setting window title
        self.setWindowTitle("Aashra")

    # method for adding new tab
    def add_new_tab(self, qurl=None, label="Blank", text="New Tab"):

        # if url is blank
        if qurl is None:
            # creating a google url
            qurl = QUrl("http://www.google.com")

        # creating a QWebEngineView object
        browser = QWebEngineView()
        browser.settings().setAttribute(
            QWebEngineSettings.FullScreenSupportEnabled, True
        )

        # setting url to browser
        browser.setUrl(qurl)

        # setting tab index
        i = self.tabs.addTab(browser, label)
        self.tabs.setCurrentIndex(i)

        # adding action to the browser when url is changed
        # update the url
        browser.urlChanged.connect(
            lambda qurl, browser=browser: self.update_urlbar(qurl, browser)
        )

        # adding action to the browser when loading is finished
        # set the tab title
        browser.loadFinished.connect(
            lambda _, i=i, browser=browser: self.tabs.setTabText(
                i, browser.page().title()
            )
        )

        browser.page().fullScreenRequested.connect(
            lambda request, browser=browser: self.handle_fullscreen_requested(
                request, browser
            )
        )

    def handle_fullscreen_requested(self, request, browser):
        request.accept()

        if request.toggleOn():
            self.showFullScreen()
            self.statusBar().hide()
            self.navtb.hide()
            self.tabs.tabBar().hide()
        else:
            self.showNormal()
            self.statusBar().show()
            self.navtb.show()
            self.tabs.tabBar().show()

    # when double clicked is pressed on tabs
    def tab_open_doubleclick(self, i):

        # checking index i.e
        # No tab under the click
        if i == -1:
            # creating a new tab
            self.add_new_tab()

    # wen tab is changed
    def current_tab_changed(self, i):

        # get the curl
        qurl = self.tabs.currentWidget().url()

        # update the url
        self.update_urlbar(qurl, self.tabs.currentWidget())

        # update the title
        self.update_title(self.tabs.currentWidget())

    # when tab is closed
    def close_current_tab(self, i):

        # if there is only one tab
        if self.tabs.count() < 2:
            # do nothing
            return

        # else remove the tab
        self.tabs.removeTab(i)

    # method for updating the title
    def update_title(self, browser):

        # if signal is not from the current tab
        if browser != self.tabs.currentWidget():
            # do nothing
            return

        # get the page title
        title = self.tabs.currentWidget().page().title()

    # action to go to home
    def navigate_home(self):

        # go to google
        self.tabs.currentWidget().setUrl(QUrl("http://www.google.com"))

    # method for navigate to url
    def navigate_to_url(self):

        # get the line edit text
        # convert it to QUrl object
        q = QUrl(self.urlbar.text())

        # if scheme is blank
        if q.scheme() == "":
            # set scheme
            q.setScheme("http")

        # set the url
        self.tabs.currentWidget().setUrl(q)

    # method to update the url
    def update_urlbar(self, q, browser=None):

        # If this signal is not from the current tab, ignore
        if browser != self.tabs.currentWidget():

            return

        # set text to the url bar
        self.urlbar.setText(q.toString())

        # set cursor position
        self.urlbar.setCursorPosition(0)

        def _downloadRequested(item):  # QWebEngineDownloadItem
            print("downloading to", item.path())
            item.accept()

        browser.page().profile().downloadRequested.connect(_downloadRequested)


# creating a PyQt5 application
app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# setting name to the application
app.setApplicationName("Aashra")

# creating MainWindow object 
window = MainWindow() 

# loop 
app.exec_()
```

Comment: +1 thanks for the informative answer.  I was wondering though, would it be possible to send a false close fullscreen request?  I have bound the `esc` key to a function, but when I just put in the code to close the fullscreen, nothing happens.  So I wanted to try to send a false request.  Would `request.toggleOff()` just work?